# Autofilling date ranges produces invalid dates (e.g. 2014/12/32)

Tags: excel, date

I'm trying to fill a column with dates. It's a long time since I used Excel, but I know that I used to be able to enter a date like "2014-12-01" and then drag it down, to auto-fill with valid dates.

However, when it gets to 31, it then continues with "2014-12-32", "2014-12-33" etc.

I have made sure the field is formatted as a date.

Comment: If it is formatted as date, this should not happen. Try entering Today() in one cell and try dragging it you will know the difference.

Comment: If I put `=TODAY()` in a cell and then drag it, all of the cells have the same (today's) date in them.

Comment: And if I put `=TODAY()+1` in the next cell, I get alternating dates when I drag the auto-fill handle: `2014-11-30 
2014-12-01 
2014-11-30 
2014-12-01 
2014-11-30 
2014-12-01`

Comment: Is the *2014-12-01* right or left aligned by default? It sounds as if it is being accepted as text (e.g. part number) and autofill is trying to intelligently increment the last digit for you. Set the cell to *General*, type in `12/1/2014` (or `1/12/2014` if your system is d/m/yy) then format the cell as yyyy-mm-dd. Drag down and it should be incrementing dates as you prefer. You can also check by setting the cell format to *Number*. 01-Dec-2014 is 41,974.

Comment: @jeeped it's definitely a date. I used `TODAY()` in a formula, as @paresh suggested.

Comment: That method was flawed. Put `=TODAY()` in a cell then `Copy, Paste Special Values` and drag down. That will prove the drag-down works and the original was interpreted as text. Your `=TODAY()+1` is not `AutoFill`, it is a formula so it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The date format you are using, yyyy-mm-dd (ex 2014-12-01) is not a predefined date format (for locale = 'English (United States)').  You need to create a custom date format and then it will work as expected.  If your locale is 'English (United Kingdom)', this date format will be listed in the Date Category.

The following was produced by doing the following:

- New workbook, Excel 2013
- Select Column A
- Format Cells...
- Select Category = Custom, enter yyyy-mm-dd
- Enter 2014-12-01 in cell A1
- Drag down to cell A36 to produce the image below

[image]

Comment: I chose this format from the list, under the Date category. It's not a custom format. If I do the exact same thing on a colleague's computer, it works fine.

Comment: If you see this format under the Date category, I assume your locale is not 'English (United States)', but possibly 'English (United Kingdom)'.

Comment: Check the format options (File > Options), your settings may be different than your colleague's.

Answer (score 0):

Mark a cell and press CTRL+POINT. (The "point" key)
Excel will autofill the cell with today's date.

### But what's more important, Excel will tell you a date format that it actually recognizes.

Afterwards, you can mark all new cells and change the date format.